# Ruby aws-sdk throws a MissingSecurityHeader

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My aws Profile looks like:

```
[my_aws_profile]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
region = us-east-1
```

My call:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1', credentials: Aws::SharedCredentials.new(profile_name: 'my_aws_profile'))

s3.put_object_acl(
  bucket: $global_config['bucket'], key: someFile_key_json, grant_read: grant_read)
```

Rerturns

```
Aws::S3::Errors::MissingSecurityHeader: Your request was missing a required header
```

What am I doing wrong? ...
How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you capture the actual request that's being sent?

Comment: Please double-check your profile: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html 
Check it out if these values were loaded